# How to iterate all chidren nodes with a name GPathResults of Xmlslurpur In groovy

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

```
 GPathResult res = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
...
...
res.order.children().findAll{it.name() == 'lineItems'}.each{it->
println 'Here I am printing'+ it.id
}
```

I am using as shown above to iterate all children with name 'lineItems' in GPathResults returned from XmlSlurpur. Even though having lineItems children, it is unable to find those, So not printing  anything. pleas suggest.

Comment: Can you give example XML?

Comment: But that didn't work for me.

Comment: With no error message and no example XML, it's impossible to tell why